# Getting information from a privatevoid

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm working on a text based RPG game. I have a String and integer I'm changing under a private void (the game is in NetBeans) and need to get the newly changed variables out of the void so it can change the location (another class, consisting of an integer and a string):

```
public String scene = new String();

public  int number; 

private void jButtonAPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
    scene = "A";
    number+=1; 
}

private void jButtonBPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
    scene = "B";
    number+=1; 
}

Location l = new Locaation(scene, number);
```

I also plan to have a switch case to change the locations depending on the user's choices. Any ideas how?

Comment: `public int getNumber() {return number;}` might be a good way

Comment: Where should I put this code?

Comment: I really need to know, where should I put the code?

Comment: maybe you should start with some tutorials https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Your two variables `scene` and `number` are `public`, so you can call it directly. If, you change `public` to `private`, then you can use `getters methods` and `setters methods` to get the actual values and modified the variables.

Here is my proposition:

```
private String scene;
private int number;

public String getScene(){ return scene;} //getter method for the variable scene

public int getNumber(){ return number;} // getter method for the variable number

public void setScene(String str){ this.scene = str;} // setter method for the variable scene

public void setNumber(int n){ this.number = n;} // setter method for the variable scene
```

Above all, you should take a look on OO design in Java.